# Jenkins can't run my Maven Selenium Project

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Actually I ran several times my project, but it didn't work.
Jenkins can't open any browser

I searched here and found two main solutions :

1. Check the allow service ... in the Jenkins server
2. use java -jar jenkins.war

The second one showed me several error that made me think that I have configuration problems in my jenkins

Here what the console return(sorry it's too long)

```html
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: Logging initialized @606ms
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:01 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFOS: Beginning extraction from war file
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
AVERTISSEMENT: Empty contextPath
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:02 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\Acer\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: Started w.@2e3967ea{/,file:/C:/Users/Acer/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\Acer\.jenkins\war}
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
AVERTISSEMENT: FAILED ServerConnector@51c668e3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
AVERTISSEMENT: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6221a451: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: Stopped ServerConnector@51c668e3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM hudson.WebAppMain$4 run
INFOS: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
        at hudson.WebAppMain$4.run(WebAppMain.java:383)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:198)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:305)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:165)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: Stopped w.@2e3967ea{/,file:/C:/Users/Acer/.jenkins/war/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\Acer\.jenkins\war}
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFOS: Winstone shutdown successfully
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
GRAVE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
        ... 7 more

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
GRAVE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:45)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1010)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:878)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins cleanUp
INFOS: Stopping Jenkins
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins$21 onAttained
INFOS: Started termination
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins$21 onTaskFailed
GRAVE: Failed NioChannelSelector.cleanUp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to inject class jenkins.slaves.NioChannelSelector
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.lookUp(TaskMethodFinder.java:125)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$20.execute(Jenkins.java:3020)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:128)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$20.execute(Jenkins.java:3020)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:263)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins._cleanUpRunTerminators(Jenkins.java:3017)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.cleanUp(Jenkins.java:2939)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)

ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins$21 onAttained
INFOS: Completed termination
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpDisconnectComputers
INFOS: Starting node disconnection
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpShutdownPluginManager
INFOS: Stopping plugin manager
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:03 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpPersistQueue
INFOS: Persisting build queue
ao¹t 03, 2016 5:27:04 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins cleanUp
INFOS: Jenkins stopped
```

Any help please ?

Thanks in advance

Hamza.

Comment: It seems there is another instance running (or the port is already used by another application).

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Yes I thought it was skype using the 8080, even closed I have the same error

Comment: do `netstat -an` and see what's using 8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack trace says that the particular port `8080` on which you are trying to run `Jenkins` is already occupied by other process.

See the log statement below:-

```
AVERTISSEMENT: FAILED ServerConnector@51c668e3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

So If you want to launch `Jenkins` you have 2 options here:-

**Option 1:**

Identify the process which has occupied port `8080`, you can do the same by using `netstat`command.

```
netstat -anp | find "portNumber"
```

Above command will give you the `Process Id` of the process that is using this port. You can then kill this process and launch `Jenkins`

**Option 2**

By Default Jenkins runs on port `8080`, instead of going for a default configuration you can run jenkins on another port using command:-

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
                                  |----------- Replace with any free port.
```

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try `netstat -an | grep 8080`, if it's there, then your Jenkins server is already started.  Try `http://localhost:8080` to finish your configuration.